# Sample Code Project Does Not Compile

Tags: twilio

I am trying to compile this [project](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/airtng-csharp) - "AirTNG App: Part 1 - Workflow Automation with Twilio - ASP.NET MVC".

I see in the Notifier.cs line 40 there is a `_client.SendMessage`.
However it does not build as there seems to be no method in the TwilioRestClient class that resolves to 'SendMessage'.

[Using Version 15.1.0 of Twilio assembly.]

Below is the code for the Notifier:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using AirTNG.Web.Domain.Twilio;
using AirTNG.Web.Models;
using AirTNG.Web.Models.Repository;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Clients;


namespace AirTNG.Web.Domain.Reservations
{
    public interface INotifier
    {
        Task<Message> SendNotificationAsync(Reservation reservation);
    }

    public class Notifier : INotifier
    {
        private readonly TwilioRestClient _client;
        private readonly IReservationsRepository _repository;

        public Notifier() : this(
            new TwilioRestClient(Credentials.AccountSid, Credentials.AuthToken),
            new ReservationsRepository()) { }

        public Notifier(TwilioRestClient client, IReservationsRepository repository)
        {
            _client = client;
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<Message> SendNotificationAsync(Reservation reservation)
        {
            var pendingReservations = await _repository.FindPendingReservationsAsync();
            if (pendingReservations.Count() > 1) return null;

            var notification = BuildNotification(reservation);
            return _client.SendMessage(notification.From, notification.To, notification.Messsage);
        }

        private static Notification BuildNotification(Reservation reservation)
        {
            var message = new StringBuilder();
            message.AppendFormat("You have a new reservation request from {0} for {1}:{2}",
                reservation.Name,
                reservation.VacationProperty.Description,
                Environment.NewLine);
            message.AppendFormat("{0}{1}",
                reservation.Message,
                Environment.NewLine);
            message.Append("Reply [accept] or [reject]");

            return new Notification
            {
                From = PhoneNumbers.Twilio,
                To = reservation.PhoneNumber,
                Messsage = message.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the content of my `packages.config` as is looks after doing an update to latest stable on all packages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="4.1.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.10" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="popper.js" version="1.14.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Portable.BouncyCastle" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Portable.JWT" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Twilio" version="5.15.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Twilio.AspNet.Common" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Twilio.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.9.7" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

[image: before and after compare]

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: just added code for the 'Notifier' class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the original sample was written in version 4 of the API. 
So to make it work with version 5 I made some changes.

Updated Code for Notifier:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AirTNG.Web.Domain.Twilio;
using AirTNG.Web.Models;
using AirTNG.Web.Models.Repository;
using Twilio.Clients;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

namespace AirTNG.Web.Domain.Reservations
{
    public interface INotifier
    {
        Task<MessageResource> SendNotificationAsync(Reservation reservation);
    }

    public class Notifier : INotifier
    {
        private readonly TwilioRestClient _client;
        private readonly IReservationsRepository _repository;

        public Notifier() : this(
            new TwilioRestClient(Credentials.AccountSid, Credentials.AuthToken),
            new ReservationsRepository())
        {
        }

        public Notifier(TwilioRestClient client, IReservationsRepository repository)
        {
            _client = client;
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<MessageResource> SendNotificationAsync(Reservation reservation)
        {
            var pendingReservations = await _repository.FindPendingReservationsAsync();
            if (pendingReservations.Count() > 1) return null;

            var notification = BuildNotification(reservation);

            var message = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
                body: notification.Messsage,
                from: notification.From,
                to: notification.To,
                client: _client
            );

            return message;
        }

        private static Notification BuildNotification(Reservation reservation)
        {
            var message = new StringBuilder();
            message.AppendFormat("You have a new reservation request from {0} for {1}:{2}",
                reservation.Name,
                reservation.VacationProperty.Description,
                Environment.NewLine);
            message.AppendFormat("{0}{1}",
                reservation.Message,
                Environment.NewLine);
            message.Append("Reply [accept] or [reject]");

            return new Notification
            {
                From = PhoneNumbers.Twilio,
                To = reservation.PhoneNumber,
                Messsage = message.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Twilio latest nuget package, the Twilio.AspNet.Mvc version 5.9.7.
Because the version that you use has dependency to older ASP.NET MVC, but the  rest of your packages dependency depends on newer version of .NET, such as Newtonsoft.Json version 11.0.x.

Please use this version of 5.9.7 instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.AspNet.Mvc/5.9.7

and chain the dependency correctly.

Comment: sorry - i had my comment on on the picture the wrong way round - corrected.  but yes I am already using it.  problem remains.